# How to compile an already built Angular app

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to compile an already built angular application. Upgrading to latest version is not possible but already built app should just compile fine.

My package.config file is

```
{
      "name": "my name",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "what does this do?",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
        "angular2-focus": "^1.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "fullcalendar": "^3.2.0",
        "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "primeng": "^5.2.4",
        "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
        "typescript": "^2.8.1",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.6.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
        "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.40",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
        "@types/q": "0.0.32",
        "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.32",
        "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
        "karma": "~1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "lodash": "^4.16.2",
        "primeng": "^4.0.1",
        "protractor": "~5.1.0",
        "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "^2.8.1"
      }
    }
```

I am getting this error when I run ng build

> Your global Angular CLI version (14.0.0) is greater than your local version (1.6.6). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
>
> @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' but 2.9.2 was found instead.
> Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
>
> Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.
>
> ```
> npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0'
> ```
>
> To disable this warning run "ng set
> warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
>
> Date: 2022-11-23T02:55:08.478Z
> Hash: 9743454dc3930ee3a8f6 Time: 4325ms chunk {inline}
> inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry]
> [rendered] chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 303
> bytes [initial] [rendered] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js,
> polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes [initial] [rendered]
> chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 675
> kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js,
> styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 588 kB [initial] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in
> src/app/nets/nets-configuration/configuration-view/configuration-view.component.ts(12,23):
> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'primeng/table'.

My Angular and node installation has

[image]

npm i shows this error

[image]

npm i --force has some warnings

[image]

I can see the package folder inside node_modules

[image]

I have deleted the node_modules folder and tried again but got this error

[image]

Comment: did you run ng serve -o?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not done npm install on your root folder as it throws that it cannot find the module 'primeng' which is in the package.json

try to do

*`npm i`*

Comment: made some edits to the original question.

Comment: try rm -r node_modules and do npm i

Comment: tried but got a different error this time. updated the original question.

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: yes, it does say python was found, just line before it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove node_modules folder and package-lock file then run npm i and it will work.
Thanks